# Improving performance of in Angular/NgRx app

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, performance, lodash

I am developing an Angular app using NgRx, one of my views has a set of filters(single and multi-select) and a table which shows records. Filters are applied one by one and on application of each filter the records in the table are filtered as per user selected values. Along with filtering of results, pagination is also updated and records are sorted before presenting to user.

User has the option to delete records as well. I render 100 records at a time (made it configurable max will be 500) but I do not want the user to apply filters again when they navigate to the next set of records

My code is working fine for upto 5k records but performance is poor for 10k records.
As the performance for >5k records(which is still a small dataset) is not upto the mark, I want to know your thoughts on where am I going wrong and what can I do to improve the performance.

Below logic takes most time in my code. I am trying to find the options for a filter which are present in the filtered records here. Column values in records constitute values of options in filters

```
const filterOptions = records.reduce((uniqueList, record) => 
                              uniqueList.concat(record[filter.key]), []);
```

Below is the full code:

```
// snippet from record-list-toolbar.component.html which has my select(filter) component
  
    <select
            [model]="filter.options"
            [multiple]="filter.multiple"
            [selectedValue]="filter.values.length ? filter.values[0] : null"
            [selectedValues]="filter.values"
            [label]="'COLUMN_NAME.' + filter.key"
            (select)="onSelect(filter.key, $event)"
            (clear)="onSelect(filter.key, $event)"
    ><select>
    
    
     // snippet from record-list-toolbar.component.ts
    
    onSelect(key: string, options: DropListOption[]): void {       
        const filtersOpt = this.filters;
        filtersOpt.forEach((filter) => {
            if (filter.key === key) {
                filter.values = [];
                for (const option of options) {
                    const selected: boolean = !!filter.values.find((opt) => opt.value === option.value);
                    filter.values = selected
                        ? filter.values.filter((opt) => opt.value === option.value)
                        : [...filter.values, option];
                }
            }
        });
        this.updateFilters.emit(filtersOpt);
    }

  // record-list.component.html 
  
    <record-list-toolbar
        [pagination]="pagination"
        [filters]="(filters$ | async)"
        (updateFilters)="updateFilters($event)"
         //more code 
    ></record-list-toolbar>
    <sub-record-list        
        [records]="records$ | async"
        [messageSort]="messageSort$ | async"
        [params] = "params$ | async"
        [columns]="columns$ | async"
        //more code
    ></sub-record-list>

    // code snippet in my record-list.component.ts
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.messages$.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)).subscribe(messages => this.messages = messages);
        this.pagination$.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)).subscribe(pagination => this.pagination = pagination);
        this.filters$ = this.store.pipe(select(MessagesSelectors.getFilters));
        this.columns$ = this.store.pipe(select(LayoutSelectors.getColumns));
        this.params$ = this.activatedRoute.params;
    }

    updateFilters(filters: any): void {        
        this.store.dispatch(new RecordsActions.RecordsUpdate(filters));       
    }

    //my reducer
    function RecordsUpdateHandler(state: StoreRecords, action) {
        const records: Record[] = filterRecordsService(state.all, action.filters);
        return {
            ...state,
            records: records,
            filters: action.filters,
        };
    }  


    //my logic to filter records using lodash functions

    import { isMatchWith, intersectionWith } from 'lodash'; 
    import { Record } from '@core/models';
    import { RecordFilter, FilterObject } from '@core/store/records';
    import { FilterOption } from '@shared/model/option-list';


    export function filterRecordsService(records: Record[], filters: RecordFilter[]): Record[] {
        const filterValues: FilterObject = filters.reduce((result, filter) => {
            if (filter.values.length) {
                result[filter.key] = filter.values.map((filterValue: FilterOption) => filterValue.value);
            }
            return result;
        }, {});
        const filteredRecords: Record[] = records.filter(
            (record: Record) => isMatchWith(record, filterValues, function (sourceValue, filterValue, key) {
                const sourceFilter: RecordFilter = filters.find((opt) => opt.key === key);
                const sourceValueArray: any[] = [
                    ...[],
                    ...sourceValue
                ];
                const intersectionArray: any[] = intersectionWith(sourceValueArray, filterValue, (a, b) => {
                    const value = sourceFilter.valueFunction ? sourceFilter.valueFunction(a) : a;
                    return value === b;
                });
                const flag: boolean = !!intersectionArray.length;
                return flag;
            }),
        );
        return filteredRecords;
    }

    export interface RecordFilter {
        key: string;
        labelFunction?: Function;
        valueFunction?: Function;
        order: number;
        multiple: boolean;
        options: FilterOption[];
        values: FilterOption[];
        filterHeight: FilterHeight;  
    }   

    export interface FilterOption {
        label: string;
        value: any;
        active?: boolean;
        payload?: any;
        count?: number;
    }   

    export interface FilterObject {
        [key: string]: string[];
    }
    
    
    //my effect code

    @Effect()
    updateFilterOptions$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(
            RecordsActions.FiltersUpdate,
            RecordsActions.FiltersReset,
            RecordsActions.Next
        ),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(RecordsSelectors.getParams))),
        switchMap(([action, params]) => [
            new RecordsActions.FiltersOptionsUpdate(),
            new RecordsActions.PaginationUpdate(),
            new RecordsActions.SortUpdate(params),
        ]),
    );

   
   //my reducer code

    function FiltersOptionsUpdateHandler(state: StoreRecords, action) {
        const filters: RecordFilter[] = filterOptionsService(state.records, state.filters);
        return {
            ...state,
            filters: filters,
        };
    }


    //my logic to update filter options based on the filtered records
    //this is the part which takes the most time
    //within this function the below logic takes the most time for each iteration 
    //const filterOptions = records.reduce((uniqueList, record) => 
    //                          uniqueList.concat(record[filter.key]), []);  

    import { uniqBy, orderBy } from 'lodash';
    import { Record } from '@core/models';
    import { RecordFilter } from '@core/store/records';
    import { FilterOption } from '@shared/model/option-list';

    export function filterOptionsService(records: Record[], filters: RecordFilter[]): RecordFilter[] {
        const newFilters: RecordFilter[] = filters.map(filter => {
            const filterOptions = records.reduce((uniqueList, record) => uniqueList.concat(record[filter.key]), []);
            const uniqueOptions = uniqBy(filterOptions, (opt) => filter.valueFunction ? filter.valueFunction(opt) : opt);

            const filterOptions: FilterOption[] = uniqueOptions.map(value => {
                return {
                    label: filter.labelFunction ? filter.labelFunction(value) : value,
                    value: filter.valueFunction ? filter.valueFunction(value) : value,
                };
            });
            filter.options = orderBy(dropListOptions, 'label');

            //here is my logic to find the count of each option, present in the filtered records
            filter.options = filter.options.map(option => ({
                ...option,
                count: filter.valueFunction
                    ? filterOptions.filter(value => filter.valueFunction(value) === option.value).length
                    : filterOptions.filter(value => value === option.value).length
            }));
            return filter;
        });
        return newFilters;
    }

    //my reducer function to update pagination

    function PaginationUpdateHandler(state: StoreRecords, action) {
        return {
            ...state,
            pagination: {
                ...state.pagination,
                page: 0,
                total: state.records.length
            },
        };
    }


    // my redcuer function to sort the resulting records

    function SortingUpdateHandler(state: StoreRecords, action) {
        const sortFunct: Function | string = action.sort.sort === 'column1' ? columnComparatorService : action.sort.sort;
        const records: Record[] = orderBy(state.records, [sortFunct, 'column2'], [action.sort.sortdir, 'asc']);
        return {
            ...state,
            params: action.sort,
            records: records
        };
    }
```

Note: I have already excluded store devtools in prod config

Comment: what do you mean by saying "performance is poor"? what action is handled slower than you expect?

Comment: @Andrei: the code is handling filter functionality. When user applies a filter , it takes >10 secs for the filtered records to be rendered, when i have around 10k records

Comment: are you using trackBy param on your ngFor? that is the easiest and yet effective performance booster in your situation

Comment: @Andrei: thanks for the reply, I read about it, but in my case the filterOptionService code is taking most of the time

Comment: are you sure? it is rendering, that takes most of the time in js apps usually. could you provide the function code that takes most of the time?

Comment: @Andrei: below piece of code is taking most time

const filterOptions = records.reduce((uniqueList, record) =>                            
                                               uniqueList.concat(record[filter.key]), []);

Comment: `const filterOptions = records.map((record) => record[filter.key]);` should be better. could the loss of performance persist, because you call this piece of code too many times? For example wrong change detection undersnding can cause that

Comment: @Andrei  thanks for trying to help me here. yes it is called many times. May iI request you to have a look at function filterOptionsService in my question above, this might help you to get an insight as to where am I going wrong

Comment: actually I thought a bit. using `.map` instead of `.reduce` should provide a boost of performance. as map version takes O(n) time and reduce one takes O(n**2) time. Did it help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226552/discussion-between-akash-sharma-and-andrei).

Comment: @Andrei I am unable to work my functionality with your suggestion, please can we discuss this on chat

Comment: @Andrei: figured it out thanks. The concat operation was costly.